# How to use non-const global variable that defined in a namespace

Tags: c++, extern

I have an header file that i put some global const variables. Now I need another project wide modifiable variable. But it gives linker error as expected. I am trying to solve the issue without using *inline* keyword. My codes:

**constants.h:**

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

namespace constants {
    bool myVar;
}

#endif // CONSTANTS_H
```

I am using this variable in my classes with `constants::myVar`. And I got a linker error. Any solution without using inline (for backward compiler compability)?

Comment: What is the linker error you have ?

Comment: You are setting yourself up for confusion if you have a non-const variable in a "constants" namespace, in a constants.h file...

Comment: Have you investigated other options? Global variables may hurt your long term maintainability quite a bit. Not so important for small projects without unit tests, but it is a good thing to learn about alternatives for globals

Comment: You shouldn't put global variable definitions in a header file. Instead, declare in the header `void setMyVar(bool var)` and `bool getMyVar()` and define these functions in a source file.

Comment: @wohlstad Wow it solved the problem. Joris Timmermans I laughed to it :) but what can i say you are right.

Comment: @feinaps added a full answer. and BTW - you should add the exact linker error to your question to make it complete.

Comment: It's exactly the same as if it's not in a namespace - the namespace is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I completely agree with the comments above about looking at alternatives for this design.
Also as you seems to be aware, c++17 inline variables offer a better solution.

Having said that, if you must keep the current design - you can do the following:

1. Change the header file to **declare** `myVar` as extern:

   ```
   namespace constants {
   //--vvvvvv------------
       extern bool myVar;
   }
   ```
2. Add constants.cpp file (if it doesn't exists yet), with a **definition** for `myVar` (preferably with some initialization):

   ```
   namespace constants {
       bool myVar;
       // or better: something like:
       bool myVar = false;
   }
   ```